# Does the file name of my XML sitemap matter? An SEO tool complains when it is not in the default location

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have added a Yoast sitemap which has the default URL `example.com/sitemap_index.xml/`

I use `rtye` to monitor different aspects of SEO which Yoast referred me to. This tells me that a critical error is not having a sitemap url of `example.com/sitemap.xml` so does not appear to recognise the URL of its referral partners sitemap.

I was wondering in the sitemap URL has any impact? I have submitted it to Google and Bing and both are aware of the URL and have indexed the subsequent URLs.

Also I have downloaded a different sitemap plugin which gives me the `/sitemap.xml` URL. Google gives the option to add additional sitemaps. would there be any benefit/disadvantage to using both sitemaps? both sitemaps essentially contain the same information

The new one appears, from what I can gather to be the better plugin. If it is recommended to use only one sitemap, would it cause issues with my rankings etc. to delete the old one and replace with the new one?

Comment: Sitemaps don't have any influence on your rankings.   At best Google will discover unlinked URLs from your sitemap and may occasionally decide to rank them, but poorly.  If you want a page to rank well, you should link to it from your other pages.   If all your pages are linked from your site, the only benefit from sitemaps is giving you extra stats in Google Search Console.   See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Answer (score 1):

You can name your xml sitemap what ever you wish.

This is just a sign of lazy design of ryte, expecting all sites to name it simply sitemap.xml

There is no benefits or disadvantages of using both of them, but also no point if they are the same.

It won't cause any issues to delete to old and and use the new one.